# Reset toggle buttons

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a toggle button. I try to reset it to neutral (no toggle set) after the form is sent in. But I have trobble doing so.. I try remove the active class bellow but it does not work. Am I missing something

```
<div class="btn-group" id="register" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default blue">
        <input type="radio" class="toggle" value="true"/>Yes
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default blue">
        <input type="radio" class="toggle" value="false"/> No
    </label>
</div>
```

Reset modal

```
$('#regModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#register radio').removeClass('active');
    $('#register radio').prop('checked', false);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides removing class clear radio selection

```
$("#register radio").prop("checked", false);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, looks right but I cannot get it to work on my code. It must be something else I am doing wrong. I updated my question to the actual code that does the reset, if you have an idea